# Android emulators with the best performance for Windows (with multitouch support)?

Tags: windows, android, emulator, touchscreen

Which android emulators out there have the best, smoothest performance and have multitouch support without needing an external touch device as a joystick?

Comment: What operating system does the emulator need to run on?

Comment: @undo I think the OP wants to emulate Android on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @RockPaperLizard, somehow I missed the title.

Comment: @undo You're welcome.  That's what I figured!  :)  I added the [tag:windows] tag as well.